# Flot plothover not working in bottom right corner

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

Showing my graph works fine but the mouse over on dots is only on the `top` 30% and `left` 10% side of graph, am I doing something wrong?

This code is fired by multiple buttons and updates, am I updating it the wrong way?

```js
function loadGraph(myArr, percent) {

    var graphData = [{
        color: '#00FF00',
        data: []
    }, {
        color: '#FF0000',
        data: []
    }, {
        color: '#FFFF00',
        data: []
    }];

    var avgPrices = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var date = new Date(myArr.items[myArr.items.length - (i + 1)].date).getTime();
        if (lines.min == true) {
            graphData[0].data[i] = [date, myArr.items[myArr.items.length - (i + 1)].lowPrice]
        };
        if (lines.max == true) {
            graphData[1].data[i] = [date, myArr.items[myArr.items.length - (i + 1)].highPrice]
        };
        if (lines.avg == true || percent) {
            graphData[2].data[i] = [date, myArr.items[myArr.items.length - (i + 1)].avgPrice]
        };
        avgPrices.push(myArr.items[myArr.items.length - (i + 1)].avgPrice);
    }

    var plotBox = $('#graph-lines');

    var plot = $.plot(plotBox, graphData, {
        series: {
            points: {
                show: true,
                radius: 5
            },
            lines: {
                show: true
            },
            shadowSize: 0
        },
        grid: {
            color: '#00cece',
            borderColor: 'transparent',
            borderWidth: 0,
            hoverable: true
        },
        xaxis: {
            mode: "time"
        },
        yaxis: {
            tickFormatter: function(val, axis) {
                if (percent) {
                    return (val * 100).toFixed(1) + '%'
                } else {
                    return val.toFixed(2)
                }
            },
        }
    });

    var previousPoint = null;
    plotBox.bind('plothover', function(event, pos, item) {
        console.log('hovering!');
        if (item) {
            if (previousPoint !== item.dataIndex) {
                previousPoint = item.dataIndex;
                $('#tooltip').remove();
                var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
                ];

                var date = new Date(item.datapoint[0]);
                var x = monthNames[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getDate() + " - " + date.getFullYear(),
                    y = item.datapoint[1];
                showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY, y + ' Interstellar Kredit (ISK) at ' + x);
            }
        } else {
            $('#tooltip').remove();
            previousPoint = null;
        }
    });

};
```

Comment: Code looks fine as it is given. Could you expand the code snippet so that it actually shows the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the debugger to see if you get an error before you get the the code that shows the tooltip?  I don't see how the browser gets past the `for` loop; it looks to me like you should be getting index out of bounds errors.

Try changing your if-statements in the following way for all three if-statements.

```
if (lines.avg == true || percent) {
            graphData[2].data.push([date, myArr.items[myArr.items.length - (i + 1)].avgPrice]);
        }
```

In the code above, I have moved the semicolon inside the then block.  Also, I am pushing the point onto the array instead of accessing the indice(the array looks to be empty where you are trying to access it).

Comment: The for loop only goes to 9 with "i < 10" so thats no issue.

I'm not getting error and the graph works fine, its only the plothover that is not working.